# Como faço para substituir caracteres de uma string, da direita para a esquerda, cumulativamente?

Tags: java, string

Estou tentando escrever uma função que recebe uma `String` e substitui os caracteres dela da **direita para a esquerda**, por zero.
Eu também gostaria de fazer isso de forma cumulativa e salvar as alterações. Por exemplo:

```
String teste = "12345678"
```

Quando eu iterar por ela, eu gostaria que o resultado fosse:

- "12345670"
- "12345600"
- "12345000"
- "12340000"... e daí por diante.

O código que escrevi até aqui:

```java
public String test = "12345678";

public String replaceFromRightToLeft(String test) {
    for (int i = test.length() -1; i >= 0; i--) {
        test.replace(test.charAt(i), '0');
    }
    return test;
}
```

Porém, quando eu executo, recebo os resultados da seguinte maneira:

- 12345670
- 12345608
- 12345078
- 12340678
- 12305678
- 12045678
- 10345678
- 02345678

Portanto, o que eu preciso de fazer para "salvar" as alterações de forma cumulativa?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Em Java, [`String`'s são imutáveis](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/strings.html), então métodos que "alteram" a `String` na verdade **retornam outra `String`** contendo as alterações. Sendo assim, você deve pegar o retorno de `replace` e atribuir na variável `test`:

```
public String replaceFromRightToLeft(String test) {
    for (int i = test.length() -1; i >= 0; i--) {
        test = test.replace(test.charAt(i), '0');
        System.out.println(test); // imprime o resultado parcial
    }
    return test;
}
```

Se você só faz `test.replace(test.charAt(i), '0')` (sem atribuir a nenhuma variável), o retorno de `replace` - que é a `String` modificada - é ignorado e "perdido".

Usando o código acima e chamando `replaceFromRightToLeft("12345678")`, o resultado será:

```
12345670
12345600
12345000
12340000
12300000
12000000
10000000
00000000
```

---

Mas tem um porém: [`replace`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace-char-char-) substitui **todas** as ocorrências do caractere, então se a `String` for, por exemplo, `"1234321"`, o resultado será:

```
0234320
0034300
0004000
0000000
0000000
0000000
0000000
```

Isso porque na primeira chamada, ela substitui **todos** os caracteres `1` por `0` (ou seja, troca tanto o primeiro quanto o último `1`), e a mesma coisa para o `2`, `3`, etc.

Então se a ideia é trocar **somente** o último caractere (e depois **somente** o penúltimo, e **somente** o antepenúltimo, etc, independente do caractere estar repetido ou não na `String`), eu sugiro não usar `replace`. Uma alternativa é iterar pelo array de `char` da própria `String` e ir mudando ele:

```
public String replaceFromRightToLeft(String test) {
    char[] chars = test.toCharArray();
    for (int i = chars.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
        chars[i] = '0';
        System.out.println(new String(chars)); // imprime o resultado parcial
    }
    return new String(chars); // retorna a String final
}
```

Ou usar um [`StringBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) (este sim mutável, podendo ser alterado à vontade):

```
public String replaceFromRightToLeft(String test) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(test);
    for (int i = sb.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        sb.setCharAt(i, '0');
        System.out.println(sb.toString()); // imprime o resultado parcial
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Testando ambas as opções acima com `"1234321"` o resultado é:

```
1234320
1234300
1234000
1230000
1200000
1000000
0000000
```

Comment: Caramba!! Que sensacional essa explicação! Muito obrigado de verdade @hkotsubo!!

Answer (score 2):

Se você dar uma olhada na descrição do replace vai ver que ele possui um retorno. No entanto no seu código você nunca está o atribuindo. O que você deveria fazer seria o seguinte:

```
public String test = "12345678";
    
    public String replaceFromRightToLeft(String test) {
        for (int i = test.length() -1; i >= 0; i--) {
            test = test.replace(test.charAt(i), '0');  //atribui retorno do replace a sua string test
        }
        return test;
    }
```